# Calling date multiple times, same results returned

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, I am attempting to track the time visitor spend on a page, however I have run into a problem.
It seems that calling `Date.getTime();` multiple times returns the same result. Here is my test code ([jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/uoa0yk1s/))

```
var d = new Date();
var start = d.getTime();
console.log(start);
window.onbeforeunload = tracktime;
function tracktime(){
    var end = d.getTime();
    console.log(end);
    console.log(end - start);
}
```

This code seems to return the same values for both start and end, and the total time spent on page is 0. Is there any other way to calculate the total time spent on the page?
Thanks

Comment: You're instantiating the `Date` object `d` one time, setting it to the current date and time. Instantiate a new `Date` object when you want to get the end time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var start = new Date().getTime();
console.log(start);

window.onbeforeunload = tracktime;

function tracktime(){
    var end = new Date().getTime();
    console.log(end);
    console.log(end - start);
}
```

Instantiate a new `Date` object each time.

Comment: Thanks! Stupid mistake :P

Comment: It's not stupid at all. I can kind of see how it'd give the impression of you requesting some sort of global/system time, but it's quite the opposite.